# Stochastic Volatility for Stocks, FTSE

Tags: volatility, models, codes, ftse, stochastic

Can someone help me with calculating Stochastic Volatility (of stocks and options) using SAS or R or Matlab please? I am new to SAS and I am trying to use Heston model, White-Hull model or any other suitable model but have no idea how to do this in SAS/ R/Matlab. Any help, any codes, any tips, any warnings are all welcome. I am using FTSE data at the moment. Thank you in advance.

Seer

Comment: Software or volatility models? Am using SAS now, can calculate simple volatility and volatility in time series. How can I calculate Stochastic Volatility parameters? What is the process for Stochastic Volatility models (for FTSE data)?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/etsug_model_sect100.htm) and what went wrong?